# Reading from pasted input with line breaks in a Bash Script

Tags: bash, scripting

I've been trying for a couple nights to get this Script to run with no luck. I'm trying to write a script using Bash that allows a user to paste a block of text, and the script will grep out the valid IP addresses from the text, and automatically ping them in order.

So far, after much modification, I'm stuck at this point:

```
    #!/bin/sh
echo Paste Text with IP Addresses
read inputtext
echo "$inputtext">inputtext.txt
grep -E -o "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}" inputtext.txt > address.txt
awk '{print $1}' < address.txt | while read ip; do
    if ping -c1 $ip >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo $ip IS UP
    else
        echo $ip IS DOWN
    fi
done
rm inputtext.txt
rm address.txt
```

After running this script, the user is prompted as desired, and if an IP address was included in the first line of text, the ping check will succeed, but then all the text after that line will be spat out onto the following command prompt. So it seems that my issue lies in when I read from user input. The only part that is being read is the first line, and once a break is encountered, the script does not considered any lines past the first in its work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, you just need an outer loop to actually read each line of user input.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo Paste Text with IP Addresses

while read -r inputtext
do 
echo "$inputtext">inputtext.txt
grep -E -o "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}" inputtext.txt > address.txt
awk '{print $1}' < address.txt | while read ip; do
    if ping -c1 $ip >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo $ip IS UP
    else
        echo $ip IS DOWN
    fi
done

rm inputtext.txt
rm address.txt
done
```

However, you can actually simplify this much further and eliminate the temporary files.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo Paste Text with IP Addresses

while read -r inputtext
do 
    ip=$(echo "$inputtext" | grep -E -o "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}"  | awk '{print $1}')

    if ping -c1 $ip >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo $ip IS UP
    else
        echo $ip IS DOWN
    fi

done
```

Comment: For some reason I am finding that when I execute this script, it takes an exorbitant amount of time to continue after 2 or 3 IP's have returned their results. I'm going to keep working at it, but any suggestions as to what may be causing this delay will be more than welcome!